# Probability of connecting with two agents in a network of three, when individual probability is different

Tags: probability

I have three nodes $(A, B, C)$ and am connecting with two of them. If I would be connecting only with one of them, the probabilities of doing that would be $A = \frac14$, $B = \frac14$ and $C = \frac12$, but I am connecting with two of them at once.

What is the probability that the nodes I will connect to will be nodes $A$ and $B$?

What is the probability that the node $C$ will be among nodes I will connect to?

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would the probability be 1/4, 1/4 and 1/2. Was that given?

Comment: Yes, the probabilities are given.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer this question reliably, since not enough information is given about the *process* of selecting two nodes.  For instance, one possibility is that we first select one node according to the probability distribution $(1/4, 1/4, 1/2)$, and then we select a second node according to that same probability distribution, discarding repeats until a node different from the first one is selected.  In that case, the probability that C is one of the selected nodes is one minus the probability that C is selected neither of the two times, which is $1 - (1/2)(1/3) = 5/6$.  Then the probability is $1/6$ that the two nodes are A and B.

Alternatively, the process could be to assign probabilities to the pairings A/B, A/C, and B/C, such that in the long run, A and B are each selected (as half of the pairing) half as often as C is selected (again as half of the pairing).  We then have $p_{AC} = p_{BC}$ and $p_{AC}+p_{BC} = 2(p_{AB}+p_{AC}) = 2(p_{AB}+p_{BC})$, which yields $p_{AB} = 0$: The pairing AB is never chosen, while the pairings AC and BC are each chosen with probability $1/2$.

These are just two possible interpretations.  Without further detail about how the pair of nodes is chosen, it's impossible to answer this question any more precisely.